# Nginx proxy pass without the location url on proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to proxy pass in nginx. here is what the config looks like  :

```
location /amazon {
        proxy_pass http://amazon.com;
    }
```

when I open domain.com/amazon it takes me to amazon.com/amazon. How should I write it so that is opens only amazon.com, without /amazon.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the URL to cut the `/amazon` prefix. Example:

```
location /amazon/ {
  rewrite /amazon/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://www.amazon.com;

  # bonus configuration for this particular host
  # may be irrelevant in your case
  proxy_set_header Host "www.amazon.com";
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```